# Wish to learn registry manipulations, its concepts right from basics

Tags: c#, registry, dllregistration, registrykey

I am totally new to registry manipulations and registry programming. **I want to learn registry concepts like, what is meant by Class_Id, GUID,Registry Key, GAC, how to manipulate these, how to use regedit etc... right from basics.**
         I just have heard of these registry related key words but dont know what are these exactly.
         If one has a good hold on registry manipulations and its concepts wonders can be done in coding. Please can anyone guide me with some material(link), so that i can learn these registry concepts from basics.

I code in .NET platform.

Thanks IN advance.

Comment: The GAC has _nothing_ to do with the registry.

Comment: terms ClassID/IID (both kind of GUID) originated from COM - they used to identify COM components/interfaces - registry just act as a storage for these values (so you may not found them in registry related literature).

Comment: Your question is much too broad, and you seem not to really know what to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try these articles

- [`The Windows Registry in C#`](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/puranindia/363/)
- [Manipulate the Windows registry with .NET](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6114709.html)

Answer (score 2):

Start with the resources on MSDN:

- [Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724871%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) - Learn about the registry.
- [Registry Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx) - Learn about the Registry Class's functionality.
- [How to: Create a Key In the Registry (Visual C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e7chcf.aspx) - Code sample writing to the registry.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I want to select even this as Answer for my question but I am not able to accept both as Answers. Is it not possible to select 2 ansers for a question in stackoverflow?

Comment: No you can only select one, but no worries. I'm glad to help out, even if I wasn't the selected answer.